# How to read all the memory of another process in windows?

Tags: windows, memory

The title really says it all, I want to have all the readable memory of another process in a buffer. I understand that I will have to use `ReadProcessMemory()`, but If I'm correct I can't just use one call to `ReadProcessMemory()` starting from address 0 for example, because there would be addresses that are non readable in the range.

I have one idea, which I believe should work, I would like to know if this is an actual solution and if there are any better solutions.

My idea would be to start from address 0 and use `VirtualQueryEx` to check if the current range is readable, if yes I read it, and in both cases I jump forward the size of the range, and repeat until `VirtualQueryEx` returns that my address is too high.

Would this actually get all the memory? Is there a better/different method?

Comment: I’d really hope that Windows doesn’t allow you reading _any_ memory from another process unless that process explicitly allows it.

Comment: Right, I assume it probably doesn't, but in this case I can run as administrator if needed and I assume then it is possible.

Comment: Reading the memory of another process is an essential part of having a debugger. How about QueryWorkingSetEx ?

Comment: Yes, that is how you do it.

Comment: So If i understand correctly the solution would be to more or less switch VirtualQueryEx with QueryWorkingSetEx? If this is the case why does VirtualQueryEx not work?

Comment: QueryWorkingSetEx is wrong. You *want* VirtualQueryEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you have surmised, you can start from address 0, use `VirtualQueryEx` to get information about that whole region of memory, including the start and end address of the region. Then you can go straight to the end of that region, which is the beginning of the next region, and use `VirtualQueryEx` to get information about *that* region. Repeat until you get to the end of the address space.

As you go along, you can use `ReadProcessMemory` to read the data. Note that there are many types of memory regions; only "committed" regions are actually associated with memory. Reading from uncommitted memory regions will fail.

Comment: Note to suggested editor: "surmise" is a real word.

Comment: NOTE: you will have to ensure that your system has sufficient memory to accommodate the read result of memory (especially if you are trying to read memory of large size process like MS Sql Server) and avoid crash.

Comment: This requires elevated privileges, right?  Hopefully?

Comment: @JimmyJames I believe most desktop operating systems allow you to read from your own processes, because they're yours and you can do what you want with them.

Comment: @user253751 I sincerely hope that's not still the case.  Do you really want your e.g. browser extensions to be able to see what you are doing in every application you have open?  When I saw this question, my first thought was that you were trying to create malware.

Comment: @JimmyJames Browsers *may* ask the OS to stop themselves from accessing other processes, just in case they get hacked. Nonetheless, the first line of defence is for browsers to not be hackable.

Comment: @user253751 Sorry that's not correct.  As documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN) the user needs the `PROCESS_VM_READ` privilege to use `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: @JimmyJames ... which is a permission that you generally do have on your own processes?

Comment: @user253751 I'm not sure that's the case but it does seem Windows allows applications to access the memory of other applications under the same user for backwards compatibility reasons.  It's not good security design, though.  It means the potential impact of malware is much higher.  It's definitely not optimal from a security perspective.

Comment: @user253751 FWIW, it seems this is not allowed in Linux without elevated privileges.  The exception being parent processes can access the memory of child processes.

Comment: @JimmyJames that's configurable. I believe the default is you can access all of your own processes, but some distributions make it more restrictive by default.

Comment: Yes, @user253751 is correct - this is how ptrace works, as used in strace; it's controlled by CAP_SYS_PTRACE.

Comment: As for browser extensions: this is why ActiveX/NPAPI extensions were phased out and the modern browser extension is some Javascript running inside the browser's containment.

Answer (score -2):

What you are asking for is quite literally an affront to the very core principles of a modern operating system.  The modern operating system, whether you are referring to *Nix or Windows, is built on the clear delineation of Kernel and User Space.  The Kernel space is really the only place where such a thing would ever be allowed, as the Kernel has the sole responsibility to map the physical memory addresses of the hardware to the virtual memory address space that is allocated to individual processes.  The memory allocation to the individual processes is bounded in the User space and is virtually mapped in such a way that you cannot reliably or explicitly refer to actual physical address locations.

This security feature is not only ingrained into the core functions of the kernel, but is also ingrained into the physical hardware of the CPU itself with codified machine instructions provided to ensure that user space is protected.

With all of that being said, if this is something you absolutely must be able to do, then your only options are to develop functionality into custom kernel modules (possible in *Nix systems, is it even possible in windows???), or you can in some circumstances implement shared memory regions between specific processes.  If your goal is to debug a specific process though then I would look into specific tools like `gdb` for inspection of symbols and memory allocations that have been allocated.  All of these things are too broad to specify in a single answer however.

Comment: But doesn't a debugger also have to have access to the process' memory?

Comment: A debugger has weird permissions that ordinary applications don’t have.

Comment: @gnasher729 not true in most cases - they're just normal user space programs, such as gdb and windbg.